# how to cancel property update in preUpdate

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to cancel a property update in a Doctrine listener's preUpdate method.

what I am doing now is:

```
/**
 * @param Subject $subject
 * @param PreUpdateEventArgs $args
 */
public function preUpdate(Subject $subject, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(Subject::class);

    foreach (Subject::ENCRYPTED_FIELDS as $fieldName => $fieldType) {
        $setter = "set" . ucfirst($fieldName);
        $oldValueDecrypted = $this->cryptService->fromEncryptedString($args->getOldValue($fieldName), $fieldType);
        if ($oldValueDecrypted == $args->getNewValue($fieldName)) {
            $subject->$setter($args->getOldValue($fieldName));
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $subject);
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunatelly it's not working as the field its updated anyway. Another thing is, when I call

```
$uow->getEntityChangeSet($subject);
```

After changing the property the old and new values are switched, so new value becomes original and the other way around. It has no effect on the database operation though.
I tried same approach in onFlush with the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [document](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/events.html#preupdate)

You can just use `$eventArgs->setNewValue($fieldName, $value)` to change the value of a field to be updated.
In your case :

```
$eventArgs->setNewValue($fieldName, $args->getOldValue($fieldName));
```

Comment: I have tried that but it does not fix the problem. The update still fires, even if the $uow->getEntityChangeSet() shows old and new value are the same.